# getting content of path

Tags: php, regex

I have folder in my domain like example.com/photos.

I need to get the content of that folder and print the picture which has a specific name like `xyz123.jpg` (`xyz` can be anything).

I tried:

```
$files1 = scandir("http://www.example.com/photos/");
```

But it returned an error

> Warning: scandir(http://www.example.com/photos/): failed to open dir: not
>   implemented in /home/egiadorg/public_html/mobil/test.php on line 3
>
> Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in
>   /home/example/public_html/test.php on line 3

Comment: Are you the owner of http://xxx.com? :D

Comment: it is not xxx.com but i am the owner of the domain that i want to get content of it:)

Comment: Then you cannot access "remote URL's" with scandir. It must be local path. ie: `/home/xxx/public_html/photos` - that should work I belive...

Comment: maybe `http://www.xxx.com/photos/` turn index off

Comment: Use a local path instead of an HTTP URI. And look into `glob('path/photos/*123.jpg')` or `GlobIterator` instead of slurping in the whole file list and filtering it manually.

Comment: For god sake please use `example.com` as an example. [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186529/help-users-create-dummy-links-that-are-not-to-unrelated-commercial-sites#comment572339_186529)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get some files from your server you can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with mask.

Also you don't need to use absolute path like "www.example.com/photos/", you should use relative path like "photos/", if it placed in root catalogue - "/www/example.com/photos" on server.

For example:

```
$arr_img = glob('photos/*.jpg');
print_r($arr_img);
```